# Как получить координаты курсора?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, мне нужно получить координаты курсора, но не на форме, а вообще вот просто где он стоит такие и координаты отображать, я попробовал в событии Form_MouseMove использовать такой код.

```
this.Text = Cursor.Position.X + " - " + Cursor.Position.Y;
```

Однако мне показывает только координаты на форме, а не по всему экрану. Так вот как можно получить координаты из всего экрана, а не только из формы? Извините, если не правильно высказался.

Answer (score 2):

Cursor.Position и Control.MousePosition возвращают всегда глобальные координаты мыши [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx).

А вот событие Mouse_Move происходит только когда курсор перемещается в пределах формы.